Sorting and skiping files in subfolder with Where-Object
So, I am a PowerShell beginner.
I Wanted to write a script, which can delete files that are older than 60 days but always leave atleast 6 files in the folder. Select-Object -skip X and Where-Object dont really work together so I tried to only focus on Where-Object. But Where{$._readcount -gt X -and x -and x} only selects the folders, not the files in the folder. What could be a Solution? Other Question don´t answer my problem because I have seen none of it filtering by LastWriteTime and skip the first X files
Those are the two pipes i tried:
Get-ChildItem $delPath -Include *.* -File -Recurse |  Sort LastWriteTime -Descending | Where-Object         {!$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit $._readcount -gt 6 } | Out-File -FilePath $workpath\$2log

 Get-ChildItem $delPath -Include *.* -File -Recurse | Sort LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -skip 2 | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit } 


Should each subfolder keep its own separate 6 files, or only keep 6 files in total under the entire root $delPath folder? In any case, if you want to keep 6 files you probably want | Select-Object -skip 6 rather than | Select-Object -skip 2.

My bad the | Select-Object -skip 2 was a test. Each subfolder should keep its own 6 files

Should each folder have 6 files older than 60 days, or just 6 files of any age?

-Include *.* is unneeded since you use -File  (unless you want to exclude extension less files), and it will not work if $delPath don't have a 'Wildcard'. You should use Get-ChildItem $delPath -File -Recurse or if you really need it use -Filter  instead of -Include like this: Get-ChildItem $delPath -Filter *.* -File -Recurse

So your main issue is that you're getting a single list that contains all files that are recursively  under the root folder, and only skipping the first 6 files from that entire list.
What you need to do instead is process the list of files from each subfolder separately and keep 6 from each list - you can do that with group-object  as follows:
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-5)

$files = get-childitem *.* -Path $delPath -File -Recurse `
    | group-object Directory `
    | foreach-object {
        $_.Group `
            | sort-object LastWriteTime -Descending `
            | Select-Object -skip 6 `
            | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit }
    }


get-childitem *.* -Path $delPath -File -Recurse - gets the list of all recursive files under the root folder (you don't need to exclude directories later). Note the -Files switch.

group-object Directory - collects the files together into groups based on their parent directory

foreach-object { ... } - processes each group of files separately

sort-object LastWriteTime -Descending - sorts the files in the current group so they're most-recent first, which lets us skip over the 6 most recent files in the next pipeline step

Select-Object -skip 6 - excludes the 6 most recent files from the results so we don't delete them

Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit } - only includes files that were changed before the cut-off date, so we keep any files that were modified on or after that date.


I've tested this with a very limited dataset locally and it seems to work, but feel free to reply with any counter-examples that it misses...

Was about to post something similar - I'd strongly suggest using Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse for the first command - that way you won't need to block for Group-Object, you're simply processing 1 folder at a time

@MathiasR.Jessen I get the bit about blocking the pipeline with group-object, but the difference with Get-ChildItem -Directory is too subtle for me to see - could you elaborate?

Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse |ForEach-Object { <# remove all but 6 files from $_ #> } - you'd then have to call Get-ChildItem -File inside the loop again - allowing you to inspect how many "younger" files you have, potentially offsetting the number of files you need to skip before deletion :)

Ah, got you. Yeah, that makes sense. I'll update the answer shortly...

Get-ChildItem  -Directory -Recurse | foreach {

    Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -File |
    Sort LastWriteTime |
    select -SkipLast 6 |
    where LastWriteTime -LT $limit |
    Remove-Item -WhatIf

}

Test it and see if the results is what you need, if so remove -WhatIf to actually delete the files.
